# How to stream video from one device to other?

Tags: streaming

I need to stream video from my Android device to other Android device over Wi-Fi, but I do not want to have a server in between. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam), or perhaps use DLNA. For example Samsung devices come with an app called AllShare which can share and access DLNA enabled devices on the network. I think IP Webcam is your best bet, though. You should be able to open the stream it creates using MX Video player or something like that.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi